# Change DOM element class name based on URL change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of code which picks up any hashchange in the URL.

It works and notices whenever somebody types a hash in.

However, I want to change the class name of a container. When I try that it changes all of the class names and I can see why.

Is there anyway to specify an index for example
    `$(".agenda-tabs li").this('class', 'active');`

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/v1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $( "#seminars" ).hide();
            $( "#speakers" ).hide();

            $(function(){

                // Bind the event.
                $(window).hashchange( function(){
                    // Alerts every time the hash changes!
                    var currenthash = location.hash;

                    $('.agenda-tabs').find('.ui-link').each(function(){
                        var innerDivId = $(this).attr('href');

                        if(innerDivId==currenthash)
                        {
                            $(".agenda-tabs li").attr('class', 'active');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(".agenda-tabs li").attr('class', '');
                        }
                    });

                })

                // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
                $(window).hashchange();
            });

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul class="agenda-tabs nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="first-tab">
                <a class="btn btn-default ui-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#t1">
                City
                <span></span>
                </a>
                <div id='conference'>
                1
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a class="btn btn-default ui-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#t2">
                Speakers
                <span></span>
                </a>
                <div id='seminars'>
                2
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="last-tab">
                <a class="btn btn-default ui-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#t3">
                Stage
                <span></span>
                </a>
                <div id='speakers'>
                3
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an anchor `<a>` element in the context variable (`this`). You just need to change the parent element `<li>`

```
// get the parent li and set it as active
$(this).closest("li").addClass('active'); // Add
```

Or

```
// get the parent li and set it as active
$(this).closest("li").removeClass('active'); // remove
```

Comment: I just updated to addClass and removeClass methods. It will not change any other class on the <li> element

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option to give your LI elements an ID? Then you can change your code to this:

```
$(".agenda-tabs li#" + currenthash).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your binding to this

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

  var currenthash = location.hash;
$(".agenda-tabs li").removeClass('active')

$('.agenda-tabs').find('.ui-link').each(function(){
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('href');

    if(innerDivId==currenthash)
    {
       $(".agenda-tabs li").addClass('active');

    }

});
```